# AngularJS doesn't create gridApi.selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting the Following error and spent last few hours trying to figure out but getting no where. Any pointers appreciated.

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.onRegisterApi (http://localhost:47167/ALMS_Scripts/Angular_Controllers/MikeSpTest.js:70:31)
    at p.renderingComplete (http://localhost:47167/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js:7:25738)
    at Object.post (http://localhost:47167/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js:7:2958)
    at http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:16:71
    at http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:81:33
    at la (http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:81:90)
    at p (http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:66:341)
    at http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:77:24
    at http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:131:20
    at m.$eval (http://localhost:47167/Scripts/angular.min.js:145:347) <div ui-i18n="en" class="grid ui-grid ng-isolate-scope grid1470663737538" id="regs" ui-grid="gridOptionsRegs">
```

Error occurs at the line 'gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged' in the script file MikeSpTest.js

My Html & scripts

```js
var app = angular.module('RegApp',
        [
            'ngRoute',
            'ui.grid',
            'ui.grid.pagination',       //data grid Pagination
            'ui.grid.resizeColumns',    //data grid Resize column
            'ui.grid.moveColumns',      //data grid Move column
            'ui.grid.pinning',          //data grid Pin column Left/Right
            'ui.grid.selection',        //data grid Select Rows
            'ui.grid.autoResize',       //data grid Enabled auto column Size
            'ui.grid.exporter',         //data grid Export Data
            'ui.grid.selection'         //data gid selection
        ]);

app.controller('RegCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'CRUDService', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, CRUDService, uiGridConstants) {

    var paginationOptions = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 25,
        sort: null
    };

    //ui-Grid Call
    $scope.GetRegulations = function () {
        $scope.loaderMore = true;
        $scope.lblMessage = 'loading please wait....!';
        $scope.loadingColor = "color-green";

        $scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function (row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex) {
            if (col.filters[0].term) {
                return 'header-filtered';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        };
    }

    //set up the grid
    $scope.gridOptionsRegs = {
        showGridFooter: false,
        enableSorting: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        useExternalSorting: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'id', field: 'id', displayName: "ID", width: '10%', pinnedLeft: true, enableFiltering: false },
            { name: 'regulation', field: 'regulation', displayName: "Regulation", width: '25%', pinnedLeft: true },
            { name: 'regulationLongTitle', field: 'regulationLongTitle', displayName: "Regulation Long Title", width: '65%', pinnedLeft: true, nableFiltering: false }
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
                if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
                    paginationOptions.sort = null;
                } else {
                    paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
                }
                getPage();
            });
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                $scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
            });
            gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
                paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                getPage();
            });
        }
    }

    var apiRouteRegulations = 'http://localhost:vvv/api/RegulationStandard/GetListRegulationsStandards';
    var getPage = function () {
        var result = CRUDService.getRegulationsStandards(apiRouteRegulations);
        result.success(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptionsRegs.totalItems = data.recordsTotal;
            var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
            $scope.gridOptionsRegs.data = data.lstRes.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
            $scope.loaderMore = false;
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    //Program flow
    $scope.GetRegulations();
    getPage();

}]);
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Regulations";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Custom References -->
<script src="~/ALMS_Scripts/Angular_Controllers/MikeSpTest.js"></script>
<script src="~/ALMS_Scripts/Services/CRUDService.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h2>regulations</h2>
        <div ng-app="RegApp">
            <div ng-controller="RegCtrl">
                <div id="regs" ui-grid="gridOptionsRegs" class="grid">
                </div> <!-- div close id="regs" -->
                <div class="loadmore">
                    <div ng-show="loaderMore" ng-class="loadingColor">
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/ng-loader.gif" />
                        {{lblMessage}}
                    </div> <!-- div close ng-show="loaderMore" -->
                </div> <!-- div close class="loadmore" -->
            </div> <!-- div close ng-controller="RegCtrl" -->
        </div> <!-- div close ng-app="RegApp" -->
    </div> <!-- div close class="col-md-10"" -->
</body>
```

##